# What happens to debuginfo when a package is upgraded? Is the debuginfo removed?

Tags: fedora, dnf

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/StackTraces#Installing_debuginfo_RPMs_using_DNF

> To install only the minimal set of debuginfo packages use the output of [`dnf debuginfo-install`] (without actually installing anything) to get the names of debuginfo packages and their respective repositories. Then construct the install command according to the following example:

```
   $ dnf --enablerepo=fedora-debuginfo --enablerepo=updates-debuginfo install <pkg-spec>-debuginfo
```

The effect of the `--enablerepo=` options is temporary.  After the command completes, the debuginfo repos are not enabled.  On the other hand, `dnf` does not immediately forget everything about the disabled debuginfo repos:

```
================================================================================
 Package                Arch      Version            Repository            Size
================================================================================
 systemd-debuginfo      x86_64    238-7.fc28.1       @fedora-debuginfo     27 M
 systemd-debugsource    x86_64    238-7.fc28.1       @fedora-debuginfo     15 M
```

## Question

When `systemd` is upgraded, will `systemd-debuginfo` be removed? Or, will `systemd-debuginfo` be somehow upgraded *from the disabled repo*? Or will `dnf` just fail? What will happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want debuginfo packages to update automatically, edit /etc/dnf/plugins/debuginfo-install.conf and change “autoupdate=0” to “autoupdate=1”.

The debuginfo packages are in a disabled repo that is temporarily enabled when you use the debuginfo-install command. Enabling autoupdate makes the debuginfo-install plugin automatically enable those repos when any *-debuginfo packages are installed.

Hope this helps.